# Adding a button to toggle between colour schemes on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I would like to add a button to my tumblr theme to toggle between two separate colour schemes -  ie  from black text on a white background to white text on a black background.

How can I add this function to my theme's html?

I have been unable to find any information so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this functionality by editing the HTML for your site using Tumblr's editor. The easiest way would probably to use a setup as follows:

CSS (inside `<style>` tags):

```
body { background-color: black; color: white; }
body.inverted { background-color: white; color: black; }

/* You can also style sub elements by selecting `body.inverted elem` etc. */
```

JS (inside `<script>` tags):

```
function invertColors() {
    var bodyClasses = document.body.classList;
    if(bodyClasses.contains("inverted")) {
        bodyClasses.remove("inverted");
    } else {
        bodyClasses.add("inverted");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="invertColors()">Invert this page's colors</button>
```

Comment: This is untested BTW